# SAS 9.3 Invalid data for variable

Tags: sas

I'm having a problem with my program in SAS running properly. There's something wrong with the way I'm acquiring data from my file and it's messing up everything inside. Here is the portion of my code messing up:

```
    data Stocks;        
    infile 'location of file.txt';
    input   @1  Stock       :   $4.
            @5  PurDate     :   mmddyy10.
            @15 PurPrice    :   dollar6.1
            @21 Number      :   4
            @25 SellDate    :   mmddyy10.
            @35 SellPrice   :   dollar6.1;

            TotalPur = Number * PurPrice;
            TotalSell = Number * SellPrice;
            Profit = TotalSell - TotalPur;
run;

proc print data=Stocks;
    var Stock PurDate PurPrice Number SellDate SellPrice TotalPur TotalSell Profit;
run;
```

And here is the data I'm working with:

```
IBM  5/21/2006 $80.0 10007/20/2006 $88.5
CSCO04/05/2005 $17.5 20009/21/2005 $23.6
MOT 03/01/2004 $14.7 50010/10/2006 $19.9
XMSR04/15/2006 $28.4 20004/15/2006 $12.7
BBY 02/15/2005 $45.2 10009/09/2006 $56.8
```

The data description is as follows:

```
Stock --> Starting Column: 1, Length: 4, Type: Char.
PurDate --> Starting Column: 5, Length: 10, Type: mm/dd/yyyy.
PurPrice --> Starting Column: 15, Length: 6, Type: Dollar Signs and Commas.
Number --> Starting Column: 21, Length: 4, Type: Num.
SellDate --> Starting Column: 25, Length: 10, Type: mm/dd/yyyy.
SellPrice --> Starting Column: 35, Length: 6, Type: Dollar Signs and Commas.
```

Every time I run it, it tells me, "NOTE: Invalid data for Number" for each line. It makes all my data off (such as the date values and whatnot). I understand that my calculated variables will not work because they're dependent on the Number data that isn't being acquired properly. I'd appreciate any direction people can give me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of all the colons ( : ).
Then add a dot ( . ) after the 4 of number to make clear it is an informat.
That should do the trick.

Comment: Indeed.  To flesh the answer out more: colons are needed for list input, not for column input.  Don't confuse the two!  List is used primarily for delimited input (ie, space, comma, etc. lists); fixed columns should be read with column (`@1 varname informat.`).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion @Shorack and your explanation of the use Joe, this is very helpful and worked! Playing around, I happened to place a $ symbol next to the 4 with a period after giving it a character attribute and for some reason that worked too, but my understanding of it only confused me more, so after following your suggestions, it all makes much more sense to me now.

Comment: The $ makes it a character variable, not a numeric variable.  That will almost certainly override any informat errors (since character variables are very flexible) but won't give you necessarily the right results.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it explicitly which columns to get Number.  Otherwise it is trying to read part of the following date.

```
data Stocks;        
infile x;

input   @1  Stock       :   $4.
        @5  PurDate     :   mmddyy10.
        @16 PurPrice    :   dollar6.1
        @22 Number      22-24
        @25 SellDate    :   mmddyy10.
        @36 SellPrice   :   dollar6.1;

format PurDate SellDate date9.;

        TotalPur = Number * PurPrice;
        TotalSell = Number * SellPrice;
        Profit = TotalSell - TotalPur;
run;
```

Comment: Also, some of your line pointers were off, this shows them corrected.