# SAS Invalid data for a variable

Tags: sas

I keep getting this error code over and over, with different line numbers of course.

```
NOTE: Invalid data for VAR4 in line 264808 30-30.
RULE:----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+
264808    F113Q1008712|201506|43003.27|R|28|332|N||||3.375|0|201412|||| 61
VAR1=F113Q1008712 VAR2=201506 VAR3=43003.27 VAR4=. VAR5=28 VAR6=332 VAR7=N VAR8=  VAR9=
VAR10=  VAR11=3.375 VAR12=0 VAR13=2 VAR14=  VAR15=  VAR16=  VAR17=  _ERROR_=1 _N_=264808
```

After enough time I this happening I get this error code:

```
WARNING: Limit set by ERRORS= option reached Further errors of this type will not be printed.
```

I'm assuming it is a problem with the delimiter (pipe '|' in my case). I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332801/sas-invalid-data)  that said:

"If it's actually tab delimited, you may need to use `dlm='09'x` instead." I guess my problem is my lack of understanding of coding. (I'm just using SAS to supplement my thesis, so a lot of this is learning as I'm going.) Where would I put `dlm='09'x` at and would it even help me in my case.

I also found a comment on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829508/sas-9-3-invalid-data-for-variable) that said:

"The $ makes it a character variable, not a numeric variable. That will almost certainly override any informat errors (since character variables are very flexible) but won't give you necessarily the right results.:)"

After reading those answers I believe I need to somehow tell SAS to accept the numerical value that can appear in Var4 and also the variable value of 'R'. Is there a way to make SAS accept either. Or am I just going to have to change all of my 'R' to a numerical value?

If it helps I'm inputting into SAS using this code:

```
proc import datafile="E:\2013\historical_data1_time_Q12013.txt"
     out=TYr2013Q1
     dbms=dlm
     replace;
     delimiter='|';
     getnames=no;
run;
```

Thanks for any help. It's much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any indication that your data are tab delimited, I see PIPE |.  VAR4 is determined by PROC IMPORT to be numeric but in line 264808 or your data it finds R.  I think the missing statement may be helpful.

Comment: What is "R" meaning?  Like "Refused" ?  Or is it a meaningful vale of some sort?

Comment: R means that it has been defaulted for so long that it got Repossessed.

Answer (score 1):

This example shows how to use the MISSING statement to read the character R as missing R .R into a numeric variable using PROC IMPORT.

[image]

```
filename FT15F001 temp;
proc import datafile=FT15F001 out=test replace dbms=dlm;
   missing r;
   delimiter='|';
   getnames=no;
   guessingrows=1;
   parmcards;
1|2|3|4
1|r|3|5
;;;;
   run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! In my data 'R' stands for whether the house was reposed or not. So by using the MISSING statement does it still count the number of 'R's'?

Comment: The reason I ask is because any number in the column Var4 implies that they defaulted on their loan. The increasing number just says for how long it's been defaulted. The 'R' is given when they have been in the default zone for so long that the house gets taken. So I want each R to be counted towards the total number of defaults. If that makes sense.

Comment: PROC IMPORTED guessed that VAR4 is numeric based on guessing rows.  Apparently the first on was in row 264808.  Having a missing value .R will allow you to summarize the data and count the number of rows with  .R.  However you have leaped from reading the data to summary perhaps that should be a new topic.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will post a new question once I get all of my data sets loaded and organized I will post a new question about that! Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: When you use missing r; what happens to the rows that have a r? do they go away? Because I don't want them to go away. Thanks.

Comment: Look at my answer again.